# Running several scripts in parallel bash script

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I have a bash script that contains other scripts inside that are run in series. However, it takes a decent amount of time to run them all. Is there a way to run these scripts in parallel to improve overall perfomance? They are independent of each other.

It looks similar to:

```
#!/bin/bash

#some code here
cppcheck.sh
churn.sh
run.sh
```

---

**Update:**

```
**git log --pretty=format: --numstat | perl -ane'$c{$F[2]} += abs($F[0]+$F[1]) 
if $F[2];END {print "$_\t$c{$_}\n" for sort keys %c}' > ${OUTPUT_DIR}/churn.txt**
sed -i -e '/deps/d;/build/d;/translations/d;/tests/d' -e 30q ${OUTPUT_DIR}/churn.txt
sort -r -n -t$'\t' -k2 ${OUTPUT_DIR}/churn.txt -o ${OUTPUT_DIR}/churn.txt
echo "set term canvas size 1200, 800; set output '${OUTPUT_DIR}/output.html'; 
unset key; set bmargin at screen 0.4; set xtics rotate by -90 scale 0,0; 
set ylabel 'Number of lines changed (total)'; set title 'Files with high churn 
level';set boxwidth 0.7; set style fill solid; set noborder; 
plot '${OUTPUT_DIR}/churn.txt' using 2:xticlabels(1) with boxes" | gnuplot
echo "finished running churn.sh!"
```

This is the code inside churn.sh. The bold command takes 40 or so secs to implement. If in a main script I put ampersand after churn.sh &, it throws an error saying sed can't read churn.txt file (since it's not created yet). It seems that it doesn't wait till the output is saved in a file. I inserted wait after that command but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Using the `&` to run it in the background will do the trick

```
cppcheck.sh &
churn.sh &
run.sh &

wait
echo "All 3 complete"
```

It will fork off a new process for each of them.

The bash [`wait`](http://ss64.com/bash/wait.html) will also come in handy as stated in the comments, if you have something to be run on the parent script, **after** these three finish.

Without an argument it will wait for all child processes to complete, and then resume execution of the parent script.

---

The issues you are facing seem to be directly related to this. Variables set are only visible to the [sub-shell in which they are defined](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27555/what-scopes-can-shell-variables-have). So, if you have `OUT_DIR` specified in the parent script, it won't be visible to the child script when it forks off. The right thing to do in this case would be to `export` the variable as an environment variable.

Comment: Additionally, a call to 'wait' will ensure the parent script doesn't exit until all the background jobs have completed

Comment: @DarkCthulhu I've already used that. The problem is the following. One line gets the data from git using --numstat and outputs it to some file. That file is then used in the next line, but since & command start executing the line and skips to the next line, the following line throws an error saying 'file doesn't exist', since it takes a while to get the data and save it in a txt file. It's almost similar issue in all the script files.

Comment: @Bdar You just said the scripts are independent of each other. If you want to add a little time between their executions, you can try `sleep n && churn.sh &`. Else, you are better off executing them in sequence.

Comment: @DarkCthulhu Yes, the scripts are independent of each other. But inside of cppcheck there is a line that creates an output(that takes about 20secs to do that) and the following line is doing a work with that output, but it seems that it skips to the next line not waiting till output has been created. It's inside the script. So, does this mean & is also active inside the script as well?

Comment: @Bdar Could you post the relevant part where you run into this issue? & shouldnt affect execution of individual scripts themselves.

Comment: @DarkCthulhu I added additional lines in my question. Can you take a look please? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Bdar I don't have any such issues. I just tested locally with something similar, even with a delay. If I had to guess, I'd guess that your `${OUTPUT_DIR}` is not getting set in the child-script. Are you doing `export OUTPUT_DIR=<value>` in your parent script? Can you check with a hardcoded OUTPUT_DIR once?

Comment: @DarkCthulhu the issue is solved, thank you!

Comment: what if one of the scripts failed,then another two no need to run,it would be better to use parallel.