# Multiple jobs on one Heroku dyno in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, worker

I've got four processes defined in my Procfile:

`web: node app.js
job1: node job1.js
job2: node job2.js
job3: node job3.js`

When I run deploy this heroku, it spins up four dynos. The jobs are light enough that they can all be run on one dyno. However, I don't want to combine all the jobs into one file.

Is there a setting or something that I can use to get `job1`,`job2`,`job3` to all run on one dyno?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run this all parallel (like they say in [Running several scripts in parallel bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644991/running-several-scripts-in-parallel-bash-script))

```
//Procfile
web: node app.js & node job1.js & node job2.js & node job3.js
```

But it can clutter the logs...

Comment: This works but yea it does clutter the logs. Let's see if anyone else comes with an alternative solution

Comment: I'm not sure how you would expect to run everything in one dyno but not clutter the logs.

Comment: you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston or similliar libs to output logs not to STDOUT, but to mongo or *sql databases