# running parallel mongodump in bash script

Tags: bash, mongodb, parallel-processing, xargs, gnu-parallel

<sup>Editor's note: This is a follow-up question to a more general one about [running a specified number of commands in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42651475/45375).</sup>

I'm trying to run this mongodb backup script for 20 mongodb servers.

```
#!/bin/bash
#daily backup for mongo db's

BACKUP_HOSTS=(example.com staging.example.com prod.example.com example1.com)
#d=$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S --date "-65 days")
d=$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S --date "-5 days")
oid=$(mongo --quiet --eval "ObjectId.fromDate(ISODate('$d'))")

cd /data/daily/
rm -r /data/daily/*

TODAY=$(date +"%y-%m-%d")
mkdir "$TODAY"

cd $TODAY

#create subfolders

for HOST in ${BACKUP_HOSTS[@]}
do
        mkdir $HOST
done

#extract mongo dumps

echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') start retrieving Mongodb backups"

for h in ${BACKUP_HOSTS[@]};do
    dbs=`mongo --eval "db.getMongo().getDBNames()" --host $h | grep '"' | tr -d '",' `
    for db in $dbs; do
       col=`mongo  $db --host $h --quiet --eval "db.getCollectionNames()" | tr -d ',"[]' `
       for collection in $col; do
            xargs -P 0 -n 1 mongodump --host $h -q "{_id:{\$gt:$oid}}" -d $db -c $collection --out /data/daily/$TODAY/$h
       done
    done
done
```

But is not working.

Tried also with:

```
parallel -P 0 -n 1 mongodump --host $h "{_id:{\$gt:$oid}}" -d $db -c $collection --out /data/daily/$TODAY/$h
```

but I get:

```
bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: General hint to debug similar syntax errors in the future: place `set -x` near the top of the script and you'll immediately see where the extra `(` comes from.

Comment: @Jens: That's good advice in general, but doesn't help in this case, because the error message is being issued by GNU Parallel, which invokes `bash` _behind the scenes_.

Comment: @mklement0 There's no GNU parallel used in the first script and it is not clear the error message doesn't happen in both. My suspicion is, the `$collection` has unquoted parentheses.

Comment: @Jens: Good guess re `$collection`, but the `-c` and `line 0` in the error message tell us that it's not the first script that produced the error. A simple way to provoke the error: `parallel echo 'a(' ::: 1`. Note how the shell command itself _is_ syntactically valid, but the way Parallel invokes it by default causes it to break. Option `-q` fixes that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
mongodump --host $h -q "{_id:{\$gt:$oid}}" -d $db -c $collection > /data/daily/$TODAY/$h &
```

The `&` in the end makes the command run in the background, thus every command that is looped will run in parallel with the previous one. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644991/running-several-scripts-in-parallel-bash-script) too.

But, I would advise you to always enclose your variables in double quotes like this `"$var"`, else many abnormalities can occur and interfere with the execution of your command.
Such as this error :

> bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

seems like it's caused by some special characters your variable **$collection** has.

Therefore, the safe version of it would be :

```
mongodump --host "$h" -q "{_id:{\$gt:$oid}}" -d "$db" -c "$collection" > /data/daily/"$TODAY"/"$h" &
```

You can check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) why and when to use double quotes for more details.

Comment: It's not explicit in the question, but the OP wants to have an _automated_ way of running _as many jobs as possibly in parallel_, without having to manually manage the partitioning into batches that can run simultaneously and waiting for jobs to end so that new ones can be started (which is what you'd have to do with `&`). Good advice re double-quoting.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following **`xargs -P`** solution:

```
for h in "${BACKUP_HOSTS[@]}";do
  dbs=$(mongo --eval "db.getMongo().getDBNames()" --host "$h" | grep '"' | tr -d '",')
  for db in $dbs; do
    mongo "$db" --host "$h" --quiet --eval "db.getCollectionNames()" | tr -d ',"[]' |
      xargs -P 0 -n 1 mongodump --host "$h" -q "{_id:{\$gt:$oid}}" -d "$db" --out "/data/daily/$TODAY/$h" -c 
  done
done
```

- `xargs` operates on *stdin* input only, whereas your solution attempt doesn't provide any stdin input; the solution above pipes the result of the collection name-retrieving `mongo` directly to `xargs`.

  - Note that this assumes that the collection names have neither embedded whitespace nor embedded `\` chars.
- `-P 0` only works with *GNU* `xargs`, which interprets `0` as: "run as many processes as possible simultaneously" (I'm unclear on how that is defined).
- Looping over command output with `for` is generally *brittle*.

  - It will only work reliably if (a) each whitespace-space separated word should be treated as its own argument and (b) these words do not contain globbing characters such as `*` - see [this Bash FAQ entry](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).
- Note how all variable references (except those known to contain *numbers* only) are *double-quoted* for robustness.
- Modern command substitution syntax `$(...)` is used instead of legacy syntax `` `...` ``, which is [preferable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

---

As for the **[GNU `parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)** command, try the following variation, *with stdin input from the collection name-retrieving `mongo` command, as above*:

```
... | parallel -P 0 -N 1 -q mongodump --host "$h" -q "{_id:{\$gt:$oid}}" -d "$db" -c {1} --out "/data/daily/$TODAY/$h"
```

- `-N 1` rather than `-n 1` allows you to control where the read-from-stdin argument is placed on the command line, using placeholder `{1}`
- `-q` ensures that passing complex commands with double quotes are passed through to the shell correctly.
- Shell variable references are double-quoted to ensure their use as-is.

---

#### Troubleshooting `xargs` / GNU `parallel` invocations:

Both `xargs` and GNU `parallel` support `-t` (GNU parallel: alias `--verbose`):

- **`-t` prints each command line, to *stderr*, *just before it is launched***.
- Caveat: With `xargs`, input quoting will not be reflected in the command printed, so you won't be able to verify argument boundaries as specified.

`xargs -t` example:

```
$ time echo '"echo 1; sleep 1" "echo 2; sleep 2" "echo 3; sleep 1.5"' |
    xargs -t -P 2 -n 1 sh -c 'eval "$1"' -
```

This yields something like:

```
sh -c eval "$1" - echo 1; sleep 1
sh -c eval "$1" - echo 2; sleep 2
2
1
sh -c eval "$1" - echo 3; sleep 1.5
3

real    0m2.535s
user    0m0.013s
sys 0m0.013s
```

Note:

- The command lines lack the original quoting around the arguments, but invocation is still performed as originally specified.
- They are printed (to stderr) immediately before the command is launched.
- As discussed, output from the commands can arrive out of order and unpredictably interleaved.
- Overall execution took about 2.5 seconds, which breaks down as follows:

  - Due to `-P 2`, the `echo 1; ...` and `echo 2; ...` commands ran in parallel, while the `echo 3; ...` command, as the *3rd* one was initially held back, because no more than 2 commands are permitted to run at a time.
  - After 1 second, the `echo 1; ...` command finished, dropping the count of running parallel processes down to 1, triggering execution of the remaining `echo 3; ...` command.
  - Therefore, because the the last command was started 1 second later and ran for 1.5 seconds, that last command finished after ca. 2.5 seconds (whereas the first 2 commands already finished after 1 second and 2 seconds, respectively).

GNU `parallel -t` example:

```
$ time echo $'echo 1; sleep 1\necho 2; sleep 2\necho 3; sleep 1.5' | 
    parallel -P 2 -q -t sh -c 'eval "$1"' -

sh -c eval\ \"\$1\" - echo\ 1\;\ sleep\ 1
sh -c eval\ \"\$1\" - echo\ 2\;\ sleep\ 2
1
sh -c eval\ \"\$1\" - echo\ 3\;\ sleep\ 1.5
2
3

real    0m2.768s
user    0m0.165s
sys 0m0.094s
```

Note:

- Because the command uses quotes to demarcate arguments and that demarcation must be passed through to `sh`, `-q` must also be specified.
- The `\`-quoting may look unusual, but it is correct shell quoting and reflects the command exactly as invoked behind the scenes.
- GNU `parallel` expects argument to be *line-separated* by default, so the shell commands are passed on individual lines using an ANSI C-quoted string (`$'...'`) with `\n` escape sequences.
- Overall processing takes longer than with `xargs`, which is the - probably negligible - price you pay for GNU `parallel`'s additional features and technological underpinning (Perl script).
- One of these additional features is the aforementioned output serialization (grouping): the *1st* command's output came *predictably* first, even though it and the 2nd command launched at the same time; the 2nd command's output wasn't printed until after *it* finished (which is why the diagnostic printing of the 3rd command line showed first).

**GNU `parallel` additionally supports `--dry-run`, which *only* prints the commands** - to *stdout* - without actually running them.

```
$ echo $'echo 1; sleep 1\necho 2; sleep 2\necho 3; sleep 1.5' |
    parallel -P 2 -q --dry-run sh -c 'eval "$1"' -

sh -c eval\ \"\$1\" - echo\ 1\;\ sleep\ 1
sh -c eval\ \"\$1\" - echo\ 2\;\ sleep\ 2
sh -c eval\ \"\$1\" - echo\ 3\;\ sleep\ 1.5
```

Comment: @basante: That's not exactly an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - there's unrelated code and one would have to have MongoDB installed, but your problem is in how you invoke `xargs`, `parallel` - most unlikely unrelated to `mongo`. I've added a troubleshooting section to my answer. See if this helps you solve the problem; if not, narrow your question down to an MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add an`&` at the end of

```
for collection in $cols; do
        mongodump --host "$h" -q "{_id:{\$gt:$oid}}" -d "$db" -c 
"$collection" --out /data/daily/$TODAY/$h
    done &
```